# Loading GIF while AJAX completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This should be quite simple but I'll be darned if I can work it out.  Just trying to get a div to display while my ajax is processing and then hide once done (I've put a sleep in there purely to test its working as locally it loads so fast I'm not sure if its working or not)!

The html page has this code in the script: -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
             $("#loadingGIF").ajaxStart(function () {
                    $(this).show();
                });

            $("#loadingGIF").ajaxStop(function () {
                window.setTimeout(partB,5000)

                $(this).hide();
            });

            function partB(){
                //just because
                }
                var scenarioID = ${testScenarioInstance.id}
                var myData = ${results as JSON}
                populateFormData(myData, scenarioID);
            });
```

There is then a div in my page like so (which I can see in the source of the page just hidden): -

```
<div id="loadingGIF" ><img src='${application.contextPath}/images/spinner.gif' height="50" width="50"></div>
```

The ready code then goes off and calls this: -

```
function populateFormData(results, scenarioID) {
    $table = $('#formList')
    for(var i in results){
        var formIDX = (results[i]["forms_idx"])
        var formID = (results[i]["form_id"])
        appendSubTable(formIDX, scenarioID, $table, formID);
    }
}
```

Which references this multiple times calling several AJAX posts: -

```
function appendSubTable(formIDX, scenarioID, $table, formID) {
    var $subTable = $table.find("#" + formIDX).find('td:eq(1)').find("div").find("table")
    var url = "**Trust me this bits OK ;) **"
    $.post(url, {
        formIDX : formIDX, scenarioID : scenarioID, formID :formID 
    }, function(data) {
        $subTable.append(data)
    }).fail(function() {

    });
}
```

Any pointers gratefully received...

Interestingly I bunged some alerts into my ajaxstart and stop and neither show up ever so I'm missing something obvious :S  When I check the console in firefox I can see that all my POSTs are completing....

Comment: try to move `$(this).hide();` inside function `partB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably add the Ajaxstart and stop global event handlers to the document node like this

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {

  $("#loadingGIF").show();

});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/ "As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document."

Comment: @jbl Completely missed that bit buried in there, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

I realized my problem, I needed to register the ajaxstart and stop to the document not the div!

So instead of this: -

```
     $("#loadingGIF").ajaxStart(function () {
            $(this).show();
        });
```

I now have: -

```
     $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            $("#loadingGIF").show();
        });
```

I assume this is because its the document that the ajax is running against not the div although my understanding there may not be 100% accurate at least this works so please tell me if I've misunderstood this! :)

@jbl, thanks for this pointer I did this to also leave the notification on screen for a few more moments just to make sure everything is loaded.

Comment: Ahh you beat me to it! by 16 seconds! Well done, I'm glad it's sorted :)